# Inserting data in table using UTL

Tags: forms, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

friends i had written a code to upload a data in newemp table using UTL code i given below but i get the error

```
  1  declare
  2       EMPNO     NUMBER(4);
  3       ENAME      VARCHAR2(10);
  4       JOB       VARCHAR2(10);
  5       MGR       NUMBER(4);
  6       HIREDATE  DATE;
  7       SAL       NUMBER(7,2);
  8       COMM      NUMBER(7,2);
  9       DEPTNO    NUMBER(2);
 10       line varchar2(100);
 11       namesfile UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
 12      begin
 13       namesfile :=UTL_FILE.FOPEN('DIPRJDIR','empdata.txt','R');
 14       loop
 15       UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(namesfile,EMPNO,4);
 16       dbms_output.put_line('EMPNO :' || EMPNO);
 17       UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(namesfile,ENAME,10);
 18       dbms_output.put_line('ENAME :' || ENAME);
 19       UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(namesfile,JOB,9);
 20       dbms_output.put_line('JOB :' || JOB);
 21       UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(namesfile,MGR,4);
 22       dbms_output.put_line('MGR :' || MGR);
 23       UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(namesfile,HIREDATE,5);
 24       dbms_output.put_line('HIREDATE :' || HIREDATE);
 25       UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(namesfile,SAL,9);
 26       dbms_output.put_line('SAL :' || SAL);
 27       UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(namesfile,COMM,9);
 28       dbms_output.put_line('COMM :' || COMM);
 29       UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(namesfile,DEPTNO,2);
 30       dbms_output.put_line('DEPTNO :' || DEPTNO);
 31       insert into newemp values(EMPNO,ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO);
 32       end loop;
 33       utl_file.fclose(namesfile);
 34*      end;
SQL> /
EMPNO :7839
ENAME :KING
JOB :PRESIDENT
MGR :0

ERROR

declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
ORA-06512: at line 23
```

and my data is in below given format
 7839KING      PRESIDENT 000017-nov-1981 005000.00 000000.0010 so Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the [UTL_FILE.GET_LINE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#i1003796) procedure, gets a VARCHAR2 as a second parameter.

If you put something else than a varchar2 oracle tries to implicitly cast it to the right type.
This worked quite well for you with numbers, but with a Date datatype, oracle will use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` which might not meet the format of string in the file.

You can fix it by using a VARCHAR2 in the `UTL_FILE.GET_LINE` call and then use `to_date` function to convert it to a date datatype.

But, there is a better way to do this job-
You can use an [external table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm) to read the file and then `insert-select` from it.

Comment: i had posted new question regarding same issuse please help me out. thanks alot for replying